# How fast is the cap() function in Golang expressed with Big-O notation?

Tags: arrays, go, big-o

Golang has both `len(array)` and `cap(array)`. The former returns the length of the array/slice (that being the amount of elements the array has); as I understand it, that function is O(1); which makes it immediate

`cap(array)` returns the capacity of the underlying array. However, is that operation O(1)? One would think that the capacity of an array is a value that the array has, and thus could see in O(1) time, but I can't tell for certain

Comment: They are both constant time operations. The slice header has len/cap, and those functions simply return those values. len(array) and cap(array) are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, do you mind writing it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal definition of slice types like:

```golang
type _slice struct {
    // referencing underlying elements
    elements unsafe.Pointer
    // number of elements and capacity
    len, cap int
}
```

For `slice`, it is `O(1)` to get `len` or `cap` field.

`len()` and `cap()` of `array` are evaluated when the program compiling.

For `array`, it is `O(1)` to get `len` or `cap` field as well.

Answer (score 6):

For slices, both `len` and `cap` simply return the corresponding values from the slice header, so they are constant time operations.

For arrays, both `len` and `cap` are compile-time constants.